# How can I redirect Spring DEBUG logs to a separate file?

Tags: java, spring, logging, kibana

So I'm trying to view my application that uses Spring framework logs in Kibana 3.
When I view the logs, there are tons of Spring's DEBUG logs, which makes it harder and frustrating to manage the application's logs.

I am using log4j2 and found a way to just disable Spring logs using

```
<Logger name="org.springframework" level="OFF"></Logger>
<Logger name="org.hibernate" level="OFF"></Logger>
<Logger name="org.apache.commons" level="OFF"></Logger>
```

in my log4j2 XML file.

What I'm trying to achieve is :

I do not want to just disable the logs, I want to separate Spring's logs from my application's logs, meaning a different file for each of them.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: You have to explicitly configure the log4j.

Comment: Can you give me an example?

Comment: Post your log4j xml configuration file.

Comment: Configure your org.springframework logger with an appender-ref to an appender that only that logger uses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<Configuration status="warn">
   <Appenders>
     <Console name="STDOUT" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
       <PatternLayout pattern="%m%n"/>
     </Console>    
     <File name="Spring" fileName="logs/spring.log">
       <PatternLayout pattern="%d %p %c{1.} [%t] %m%n"/>
     </File>
   </Appenders>
   <Loggers>
      <!-- Route Spring logs to their own file and do not include in root logger -->
      <Logger name="org.springframework" level="INFO" additivity="false">
        <AppenderRef ref="Spring"/>
     </Logger>    
     <Root level="error">
        <AppenderRef ref="STDOUT"/>
     </Root>
   </Loggers>
 </Configuration>
```

Comment: Thank you very much brother